# Simple multithread functionality to be added in existing application

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class which works fine. Now I want to calculate something and log it but that shouldnt affect the performance, so want to create a thread and thinking thread should achieve that. But have never done threading before. So thinking to implmenet runnable and run class. DOnt know how can i achieve this.

```
class Test implements ServiceA, Runnable
{

    private final ServiceA one;
    private final ServiceA two;
    Test(ServiceA one, ServiceA two)
       {
        this.one = one;
        this.two= two;
    }

    @override
    public objectA calculate(TInput input)
    {
        objectA objAOne = one.Find(input);
        // First I just had "return one.calculate(input)";
        // Now I want to create a thread and that should do 2 things.
        // 1. call "two.calculate(input)" -- App Shouldnt wait for the response of this
        // 2. log this (which i know).
        //How can i create a thread here that can help me achieve this 

        return objAOne ;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {       
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me on this ?

Comment: are you using java 8?

Comment: @OznOg Yes using Java 8

Comment: @OznOg ANy idea on this ?

Comment: This is a bit confusing. What do you mean by "create a thread and thinking thread"? Is this two threads or three threads (the 2 you mention plus the main thread)? If so what would each thread be doing in their individual execution's? How do they interact with each other? How does the code you've supplied relate to the question? Have you searched for "Java Threading examples" or "Java Threading Tutorial", there are lots of resources out there.

Perhaps after looking at some examples,when you have a specific problem that is not working, you can update the question with that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is hard to understand multi threading in the begging. Here is simple example which may give you direction

```java
public class MyTest {
    static class MyWorker implements Runnable {
        public String result = "not calculated yet";
        private String params;

        public MyWorker(String params) {
            this.params = params;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // calculate here
            this.result = "Result of calculation for " + this.params;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MyWorker w1 = new MyWorker("One");
        MyWorker w2 = new MyWorker("Two");

        new Thread(w1).start();
        new Thread(w2).start();

        System.out.println("0 w1 result: " + w1.result);
        System.out.println("1 w2 result: " + w2.result);

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        System.out.println("2 w1 result: " + w1.result);
        System.out.println("3 w2 result: " + w2.result);
    }
}
```

Possible output:

```
0 w1 result: not calculated yet
1 w2 result: not calculated yet
2 w1 result: Result of calculation for One
3 w2 result: Result of calculation for Two

Process finished with exit code 0
```